# How to upload source context for an Android project with sentry

Tags: android, sentry

I'm building an android app which uses sentry to log errors.
However I would like to enhance my stack traces with the original source code.

This should be supported according to Sentry's [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/data-management/debug-files/source-context/), however I can't figure out which steps to take.

In have a working setup to resolve ProGuard symbols, and I have tried to generate source bundles using `sentry-cli upload-dif --include-sources` and  `sentry-cli difutil bundle-sources`. However I haven't got either one to work.

If someone has tackled this problem before and has managed to get their Android app source code in Sentry, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet. But there's a feature request for this tracked on GitHub:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/633